# Como mudar o titulo de uma activity?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma activity e estou precisando mudar o seu titulo programaticamente, achei uma forma mas ela não funciona para mim, vejam só:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_relatorio);

    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setTitle("Relatório de Vendas");
}
```

Tentei usar na api 21 e 22 e o titulo continua aparecendo o nome do aplicativo e o texto do `setTitle()` não é exibido. Como pode ser feito esta alteração?

Comment: Eu faço via Manifest, mas o engraçado é que no último app que fiz, tem activity que aparece o título e outras não, e está tudo certinho no XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método para alterar o titulo é `setTitle` de facto, mas de `Activity` e não de `Window`

Uma vez que a sua classe estende `Activity` basta chamar diretamente:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_relatorio);

    setTitle("Relatório de Vendas");
}
```

[Documentação para o método `setTitle` de `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 4):

Apenas uma forma a mais

Você pode **tentar** mudar via xml também.

No AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:label="Relatório de vendas"
```

Ou, com a referência do strings

```
android:label="@strings/Relatorio_de_vendas"
```

Por exemplo:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/splash_activity_title" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```